# Firebase orderByChild not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get ordered list of my firebase nodes

```
inboxMessageFetch(mobileNumber, firebaseToken) { 
    return firebase.database().ref(`messaging/${mobileNumber}/inbox`).orderByChild("time")
        .on('value', snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                this.inboxMessages = snapshot.val();
                console.log('FB', this.inboxMessages);
            }
        });
}
```

This is my database 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

The snapshot you receive in your callback contains the keys and the values of all items, as well as information about their relative ordering. When you call `snapshot.val()` unfortunately the information on the ordering is lost.

Your code needs to take this into consideration, and should use `snapshot.forEach()` to loop over the results in the requested order:

```
inboxMessageFetch(mobileNumber, firebaseToken) { 
  firebase.database().ref(`messaging/${mobileNumber}/inbox`).orderByChild("time")
    .on('value', snapshot => {
        this.inboxMessages = [];
        snapshot.forEach((messageSnapshot) {
            console.log(messageSnapshot.key, messageSnapshot.val();
            this.inboxMessages.push(messageSnapshot.val());
        });
        console.log(this.inboxMessages);
    });
}
```

Comment: How will I assign the value to `this.inboxMessages` ?